# What would be a use case for disposing a test observer before subscription?

Tags: rx-java, rx-java2

The Observable class has this method:

`public final TestObserver<T> test(boolean dispose)`

What would be a use case for disposing the test observer before subscribing to the observable?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are building a custom operator, you have to make sure that it conforms with the reactive streams [specification](https://github.com/reactive-streams/reactive-streams-jvm). For example, it states the following for [Subscription](https://github.com/reactive-streams/reactive-streams-jvm#3-subscription-code):

> 6 - After the Subscription is cancelled, additional Subscription.request(long n) MUST be NOPs.
>
> 7 - After the Subscription is cancelled, additional Subscription.cancel() MUST be NOPs.

That dispose method is just a [convenient](https://github.com/ReactiveX/RxJava/blob/a1693ecc9215027a7a3eae75272979ebb4d79a27/src/main/java/io/reactivex/rxjava3/core/Single.java#L4055) method to help you to test these scenarios. You can check how it's being used in the RxJava code base [here](https://github.com/ReactiveX/RxJava/search?q=%22test%28true%29%22&unscoped_q=%22test%28true%29%22) to unit test operators like Cache, Concat, Timeout..

Here is an [example](https://github.com/ReactiveX/RxJava/blob/9a36930bff81770c98b5babe58621fd8e49dba2d/src/test/java/io/reactivex/rxjava3/internal/operators/single/SingleTimeoutTest.java#L79) for the Timeout operator:

```
    @Test
    public void disposeWhenFallback() {
        TestScheduler sch = new TestScheduler();

        SingleSubject<Integer> subj = SingleSubject.create();

        subj.timeout(1, TimeUnit.SECONDS, sch, Single.just(1))
        .test(true)
        .assertEmpty();

        assertFalse(subj.hasObservers());
    }
```

It checks that the stream is empty when subscribing to it after the observer has been disposed.

Comment: Thanks, it makes sense.